# How to only change the valua of an attribute for an XML message

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I am trying to use XSLT to change the value of an attribute in this XML SOAP message, used for the test:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <env:Header>
    <wsa:To>http://10.141.160.82:8221/EchoWS/HelloWorldPort</wsa:To>
    <wsa:Action>http://ws.test.support.oracle.com/HelloWorld/sayHelloRequest</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:6B291C103CAA11E3BF2AB9016B2C3D3A</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:6B291C103CAA11E3BF2AB9016B2C3D3A</wsa:RelatesTo>
    <wsa:ReplyTo>
      <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
      <wsa:ReferenceParameters>
        <instra:tracking.ecid xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">863df39044fd7fd4:-419f3903:141cd7e2379:-8000-00000000000011e3</instra:tracking.ecid>
        <instra:tracking.conversationId xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">urn:6B291C103CAA11E3BF2AB9016B2C3D3A</instra:tracking.conversationId>
        <instra:tracking.parentComponentInstanceId xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">reference:3</instra:tracking.parentComponentInstanceId>
        <instra:tracking.compositeInstanceCreatedTime xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">2013-10-24T08:47:19.112-04:00</instra:tracking.compositeInstanceCreatedTime>
      </wsa:ReferenceParameters>
    </wsa:ReplyTo>
    <wsa:FaultTo>
      <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
      <wsa:ReferenceParameters>
        <instra:tracking.ecid xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">863df39044fd7fd4:-419f3903:141cd7e2379:-8000-00000000000011e3</instra:tracking.ecid>
        <instra:tracking.conversationId xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">urn:6B291C103CAA11E3BF2AB9016B2C3D3A</instra:tracking.conversationId>
        <instra:tracking.parentComponentInstanceId xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">reference:3</instra:tracking.parentComponentInstanceId>
        <instra:tracking.compositeInstanceCreatedTime xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">2013-10-24T08:47:19.112-04:00</instra:tracking.compositeInstanceCreatedTime>
      </wsa:ReferenceParameters>
    </wsa:FaultTo>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" env:mustUnderstand="1">
      <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-wDovd4kFRR1RutxItzNNHw22">
        <wsse:Username>weblogic</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">manager03</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <sayHello xmlns="http://ws.test.support.oracle.com/">
      <arg0 xmlns="">Miguel</arg0>
    </sayHello>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

From this the only part I need to change is,
from:

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" env:mustUnderstand="1">
```

to:

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" env:mustUnderstand="0">
```

This is to change the `env:mustUnderstand="1"` to `"0"`.

I have been trying but have not been able to do it.
Can you help me with an XSLT which I can use for this?

Comment: There are a number of SO posts that cover this very thing. Look up identity template for a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

used XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Security']">
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" env:mustUnderstand="xxxxx">
        <xsl:copy-of select="child::*"/>
    </wsse:Security>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <env:Header>
    <wsa:To>http://10.141.160.82:8221/EchoWS/HelloWorldPort</wsa:To>
    <wsa:Action>http://ws.test.support.oracle.com/HelloWorld/sayHelloRequest</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:6B291C103CAA11E3BF2AB9016B2C3D3A</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:6B291C103CAA11E3BF2AB9016B2C3D3A</wsa:RelatesTo>
    <wsa:ReplyTo>
      <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
      <wsa:ReferenceParameters>
        <instra:tracking.ecid xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">863df39044fd7fd4:-419f3903:141cd7e2379:-8000-00000000000011e3</instra:tracking.ecid>
        <instra:tracking.conversationId xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">urn:6B291C103CAA11E3BF2AB9016B2C3D3A</instra:tracking.conversationId>
        <instra:tracking.parentComponentInstanceId xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">reference:3</instra:tracking.parentComponentInstanceId>
        <instra:tracking.compositeInstanceCreatedTime xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">2013-10-24T08:47:19.112-04:00</instra:tracking.compositeInstanceCreatedTime>
      </wsa:ReferenceParameters>
    </wsa:ReplyTo>
    <wsa:FaultTo>
      <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
      <wsa:ReferenceParameters>
        <instra:tracking.ecid xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">863df39044fd7fd4:-419f3903:141cd7e2379:-8000-00000000000011e3</instra:tracking.ecid>
        <instra:tracking.conversationId xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">urn:6B291C103CAA11E3BF2AB9016B2C3D3A</instra:tracking.conversationId>
        <instra:tracking.parentComponentInstanceId xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">reference:3</instra:tracking.parentComponentInstanceId>
        <instra:tracking.compositeInstanceCreatedTime xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">2013-10-24T08:47:19.112-04:00</instra:tracking.compositeInstanceCreatedTime>
      </wsa:ReferenceParameters>
    </wsa:FaultTo>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" env:mustUnderstand="xxxxx"><wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-wDovd4kFRR1RutxItzNNHw22">
        <wsse:Username>weblogic</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">manager03</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <sayHello xmlns="http://ws.test.support.oracle.com/">
      <arg0 xmlns="">Miguel</arg0>
    </sayHello>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach to this sort of problem in XSLT is to define an *identity template* that copies everything unchanged from input to output, except where overridden by more specific templates, then define such templates for the things you want to change.  In this case the only thing you want to change is that one attribute.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- match env:mustUnderstand attribute only on the Security header -->
  <xsl:template match="w:Security/@env:mustUnderstand"
        xmlns:w="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
        xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <!-- and replace it with env:mustUnderstand="0" -->
    <xsl:attribute name="env:mustUnderstand">0</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't think you need to bother checking for the specific "1" value in this case, but if you did need to check it (e.g. if you want to change "1" to "0" but leave other values alone) then you could use

```
match="w:Security/@env:mustUnderstand[. = '1']"
```